# How to add point images to a map using javascript?

Tags: highcharts, maps

I am using highcharts map and would like to add point location on it using real coordinates. How can i do this in javascript any links? or any suggestions of customizable map that allows me to enter images as locations?

Comment: Highmaps are using own coordinates, according to pixel values. Like in example here: http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/mapline-mappoint - you can find x/y values for each of cities.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch click event on the chart, then you get coordinates for particular point (x/y). Last step is using it in data.

Example: http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/mapline-mappoint

Another way to approach this would be to import the GeoJSON file ("fr-all-mainland.geo.json") in a compatible editor (for example QGIS) and plot the cities there, then inverting the y-coordinate. This would be similar to plotting the cities in Inkscape, except you would be working with the GeoJSON file instead of the SVG.

Please visit the related topic: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/5780574-add-ability-to-plot-points-based-on-longitude-lati